# Does DegreeGraphDistribution sample uniformly?

Tags: bugs, graphs-and-networks, probability-or-statistics, distributions, implementation-details

**Bug introduced in 10.0 or earlier and persisting through 12.1**

 The first symptom (histogram below) is gone in 12.0. The second (fraction of connected graphs) persists, showing that the sampling is still not uniform.

---

There are two undirected labelled simple graphs with the degree sequence `{1, 2, 2, 1}`:

[image]

`RandomGraph[DegreeGraphDistribution[{1,2,2,1}]]` will generate both, but not with *exactly* the same probability.  The former seems to be generated slightly less often than the latter.

Here's proof:

```
ParallelTable[
  Table[RandomGraph@DegreeGraphDistribution[{1, 2, 2, 1}], {5000}] // 
      CountsBy[AdjacencyMatrix] // KeySort // Values // Apply[Divide],
  {500}
] // Histogram
```

[image]

The histogram you see above is for the ratio of the frequency of the first graph to the second (in samples of 5000).

**Questions:**

- Is this expected or is it a bug?  I am looking for an explanation of why the two graphs are not constructed with equal probability.
- What method does `RandomGraph[DegreeGraphDistribution[...]]` use in M11.2?

Some methods would give approximate results, which is why documenting the method being used is important.  A few years ago I asked Wolfram Support about the method, and I was told that it is based on the configuration model.  I cannot see how this bias would arise with such a method.

---

#### Update 2019 March

Here's another, independent method to demonstrate that the sampling is not uniform. We are going to compute what fraction of the graphs with a given degree sequence are connected, and show that the estimate obtained with `DegreeGraphDistribution` is incorrect.

```
$Version
(* "11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)" *)
```

Create degree sequence:

```
ds = VertexDegree@KaryTree[9];
```

Approximate the fraction of connected graphs using `RandomGraph[DegreeGraphDistribution[...]]`. Multiple repetitions will give us an idea about the accuracy of the approximation.

```
Table[
 Mean@N@Boole[
    ConnectedGraphQ /@ 
     RandomGraph[DegreeGraphDistribution[ds], 100000]], {10}]
(* {0.43967, 0.44448, 0.44331, 0.44311, 0.44306, 0.4409, 0.44043, 0.44013, 0.44418, 0.44443} *)

Mean[%]
(* 0.44237 *)
```

Now we compute the exact result. This effectively generates *all* realizations of the degree sequence.

```
gs = 
  RandomGraph[DegreeGraphDistribution[ds], 100000] // 
   DeleteDuplicatesBy[AdjacencyMatrix];

Length[gs]
(* 1335 *)
```

(Yes, this is a hack, however I verified the result with an exact generation program that is too long to include here.)

The true fraction is approximately 0.472.

```
Mean@N@Boole[ConnectedGraphQ /@ gs]
(* 0.47191 *)
```

As you can see above, from `DegreeGraphDistribution` we consistently get 0.44, which is close, but clearly different.

For my work, I needed reliable estimates of this fraction for degree sequences which have many more realizations than what can be practically generated. Due to this failure, using `DegreeGraphDistribution` is not an option.

Comment: It looks quiet even to me: In[43]:= Values[
 CountsBy[RandomGraph[DegreeGraphDistribution[{1, 2, 2, 1}], {5000}], 
  AdjacencyMatrix]]

Out[43]= {2507, 2493}

Comment: @halmir What do you mean by "quiet"?  I think it's a typo, and I can't quite figure out what you meant.  Note that a `KeySort` is missing in front of the `CountsBy` in the input you showed—that's essential for comparing repeated runs.

Comment: If you run `Values@KeySort@CountsBy[RandomGraph[
    DegreeGraphDistribution[{1, 2, 2, 1}], {20000}], AdjacencyMatrix]` repeatedly, the first entry is almost always less than 10000 and the second is greater than 10000.

Comment: All permutations of the given vertex degree list result in *skewed* histograms with `{2,2,1,1}` being the only exception. It turns out as one would expect for randomness, e.g. mode at 1.0. Should that not be invariant to order?

Comment: I have called this a "bug" now as at least there should be words of caution in the documentation imo.

Comment: @gwr There's also the issue that `DegreeGraphDistribution` is never explained in the documentation. We *expect* uniform sampling, but the documentation only says that it is a "degree graph distribution", which is not a standard term. In fact, if you use `SelfLoops -> True`, the sampling is no longer uniform for graphs with loops. That would be expected for the configuration model, but there's no mention in the documentation that that is what a "degree graph distribution" is supposed to mean.

Comment: Furthermore, even if we don't set `SelfLoops -> True`, Mathematica will automatically create loops (and break uniform sampling) if the degree sequence is not realizable by a simple graph.

Comment: @halmir Is it that DegreeGraphDistribution does not implement the configuration model with rejecting non-simple graphs in a direct way, but uses some trick to speed up things, and this trick introduces a small bias?  If so, I'd be interested in what that trick is.  I couldn't quite implement the configuration model in such a way that it's as fast as `RandomGraph[DegreeGraphDistribution[...]]`

Comment: @halmir I included another example, which also illustrates how this is a problem for my work.  I do have an independent implementation of the configuration model in IGraph/M. However, `RandomGraph[DegreeGraphDistribution[...]]` is faster. I would like to know how it works, and whether it can be fixed without slowing it down.