# How to create random graph with certain properties?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, random

My question consists of two parts.

1. How to create a random undirected connected graph s.t. the probability of the event "The degree of a vertex equals k"
   is equal to  $\frac{k^{-\gamma }}{\zeta (\gamma )},\,k=1,2,\dots,\,\gamma >1$?
   Of course, I looked in [RandomGraph](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomGraph.html) , but didn't find the answer. My attempt `RandomGraph[ZipfDistribution[2]]` is not successful.
2. Additionally, let the probability of the event "The vertices of degrees $k_1$ and $k_2,\, k_1\ge k_2,\,k_2\ge 1$ are connected by the 
   edge" be equal to $$\frac {k_1^{-\gamma}k_2^{-\epsilon}} {\sum _{k_2=1}^{\infty } k_2^{-\epsilon } \zeta (\gamma ,k_2)},\,\gamma > 1, \epsilon >1,\,\gamma \neq \epsilon.$$

The question is motivated by the article Lazaros K. Gallos, Chaoming Song, and Hernán A. Makse, Phis. Rev. L. 100, 248701 (2008).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What does it mean to sample random graphs with certain properties? If the property applies to individual graphs, then "random" would mean that we assign the same probability to each graph that satisfies the property (and exclude the rest). Sampling from such a distribution is usually a difficult problem. It is literally a research-level problem for each constraint you come up with. But if you're lucky, someone has already solved that problem for your specific constraint.

The first constraint you mention refers to the *degree distribution*. Look up the Chung–Lu model for this. In [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM), [`IGStaticFitnessGame`](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGDocumentation/#igstaticfitnessgame) and [`IGStaticPowerLawGame`](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGDocumentation/#igstaticpowerlawgame) implement a variant of this. In this model, you can set the *expected* degree of each vertex. The actual degree of that vertex in a single sample may vary significantly. It is only the average taken across many samples that will match.

Another thing you can do is to sample from the set of graphs which have a specific degree sequence: the degree of each vertex is fixed. First, you can sample degrees from an arbitrary distribution. Then check that a graph with these degrees exists (this is called graphicality, see `IGGraphicalQ`). Then use `IGDegreeSequenceGame` to sample graphs with that degree sequence. *Do read the [`IGDegreeSequenceGame` documentation](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGDocumentation/#igdegreesequencegame) and choose the appropriate method!* Not all implemented methods sample uniformly; the default one doesn't. The good method choices are the configuration model, which is only usable for small or very sparse graphs (otherwise it's too slow) or the Viger–Latapy method, which samples only connected graphs (in case you need that). Yet another alternative is to create first a single graph, using `IGRealizeDegreeSequence`, then "shuffle its edges around" using `IGRewire`. This also leads to uniform sampling provided in the limit of a large number of rewiring steps in `IGRewire`.

The built-in `DegeeGraphDistribution` should also be able to sample graphs with certain degrees, but [its behaviour is fishy](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/167450/does-degreegraphdistribution-sample-uniformly) and I was never able to extract a satisfactory response from Wolfram about what is going on: the developers simply refuse to respond. That's a big red flag for me, and I always avoid this function for this reason. You just don't know what you're getting.

---

As for your second question, if you want to control the probability of connection between vertices of certain degrees, the keyword is "joint degree matrix". I do not have a ready-made program for you, but you can look at https://doi.org/10.1137/130929874 and https://doi.org/10.1145/2133803.2330086

---

#### Examples

Sample the degrees from a Zipf distribution:

```
SeedRandom[15]
degrees = ReverseSort@RandomVariate[ZipfDistribution[1.2], 100]
(* {96, 75, 14, 11, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, \
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, \
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, \
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, \
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1} *)
```

There may be no simple graph (i.e. no self-loops or multi-edges) having these degrees. `IGGraphicalQ` tests this:

```
IGGraphicalQ[degrees]
(* False *)
```

But we can still use them as input to the Chung–Lu model, as this model only produces these degrees on average. Here's the average of each vertex's degree over many sampled graphs:

```
Mean@N@Table[
   VertexDegree@
    IGStaticFitnessGame[Total[degrees]/2, degrees, 
      MultiEdges -> True,
      SelfLoops -> True],
   {1000}
   ]


(* {96.031, 75.155, 13.977, 10.881, 6.018, 4.047, 3.862, \
3.999, 4.042, 2.959, 2.857, 2.957, 2.986, 2.955, 3.02, 3.011, 1.974, \
1.998, 2.077, 2.012, 1.979, 2.005, 1.961, 2.066, 1.935, 2.003, 2.031, \
2.009, 1.934, 1.97, 1.956, 2.014, 2.018, 1.917, 2.069, 1.957, 1.991, \
2.064, 2.009, 0.987, 1.002, 1.007, 0.996, 1.068, 1.028, 1.036, 0.99, \
0.953, 1.019, 0.992, 1.043, 1.027, 0.975, 1.004, 0.983, 1.068, 0.992, \
1.044, 0.994, 0.979, 1.006, 1.024, 1.027, 0.968, 0.974, 0.925, 1.07, \
1.009, 0.999, 0.976, 1.018, 1.045, 1.04, 1.014, 0.976, 1.031, 0.995, \
0.979, 0.968, 0.97, 0.991, 1.017, 0.996, 0.973, 0.984, 0.988, 1.04, \
0.999, 1.016, 0.993, 0.99, 1.001, 1.031, 1.024, 0.956, 1.069, 1.005, \
1.026, 0.981, 1.013} *)
```

In a single sample, the degrees will not match perfectly:

```
VertexDegree@
 IGStaticFitnessGame[Total[degrees]/2, degrees, MultiEdges -> True, 
  SelfLoops -> True]
(* {83, 74, 16, 9, 3, 4, 1, 5, 7, 6, 2, 2, 5, 4, 5, 3, 0, 2, \
0, 3, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 5, 1, 1, 7, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0, 1, \
3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, \
2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 4, \
0, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0} *)
```

If we disable self-loops and multi-edges, then they won't even match well in the average. This is not that surprising, since this degree sequence wasn't graphical.

```
Mean@N@Table[
   VertexDegree@IGStaticFitnessGame[Total[degrees]/2, degrees],
   {1000}
   ]
(* {51.954, 44.692, 13.035, 10.82, 6.927, 5.169, 5.095, 5.172, \
5.218, 4.202, 4.167, 4.183, 4.119, 4.094, 4.076, 4.063, 2.971, 3.043, \
3.133, 2.941, 3.033, 2.961, 3.018, 2.945, 2.993, 2.951, 3.006, 2.974, \
3.064, 2.907, 3.017, 2.956, 3.046, 3.043, 3.021, 3.03, 3.024, 2.987, \
2.968, 1.663, 1.681, 1.654, 1.656, 1.643, 1.606, 1.662, 1.604, 1.653, \
1.646, 1.679, 1.673, 1.579, 1.683, 1.702, 1.655, 1.583, 1.6, 1.624, \
1.537, 1.643, 1.662, 1.638, 1.603, 1.69, 1.689, 1.7, 1.609, 1.591, \
1.646, 1.557, 1.559, 1.65, 1.616, 1.661, 1.648, 1.622, 1.643, 1.592, \
1.688, 1.608, 1.644, 1.66, 1.63, 1.646, 1.614, 1.655, 1.622, 1.665, \
1.618, 1.69, 1.602, 1.703, 1.629, 1.635, 1.669, 1.669, 1.627, 1.592, \
1.628, 1.686} *)
```

Sample a graphical degree sequence from a Zipf distribution:

```
degrees = 
  ReverseSort@
   IGTryUntil[IGGraphicalQ]@RandomVariate[ZipfDistribution[1.6], 100];
```

Now we can create a simple graph having *exactly* these degrees:

```
IGDegreeSequenceGame[degrees]
```

[image]

```
VertexDegree[%] == degrees
(* True *)
```

Note that with the default method, the sampling won't be uniform. To get uniform sampling, use

```
IGDegreeSequenceGame[degrees, Method -> "ConfigurationModelSimple"]
```

This will be unusably slow if the exponent of the Zipf distribution is too low. `Method -> "VigerLatapy"` is much faster and it does sample *approximately* uniformly, but it only samples connected graphs. To check if there is a connected graph having certain degrees, it is sufficient to check that it has at least as many edges as its vertices minus one.

```
potenticallyConnectedQ[degrees_] := 
 Total[degrees]/2 >= Length[degrees] - 1
```

This is not true for this degree sequence.

But we can use yet another approximately uniform sampling method: create one graph with the given degrees and rewire its edges with degree-preserving edge swaps.

```
IGRewire[
 IGRealizeDegreeSequence[degrees],
 1000
]
```

To obtain several samples, use something similar to:

```
NestList[IGRewire[#, 1000] &, IGRealizeDegreeSequence[degrees], 10]
```

Here I used 1000 rewiring trials. If we use too few, then subsequent samples will not be statistically independent.

---

**Update:**

If you only want connected graphs, use `IGDegreeSequenceGame[..., Method -> "VigerLatapy"]`

```
degrees = 
  IGTryUntil[potenticallyConnectedQ[#] && IGGraphicalQ[#] &]@
   RandomVariate[ZipfDistribution[1.6], 100];

IGDegreeSequenceGame[degrees, Method -> "VigerLatapy"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solid answer. First,  I don't understand your " Note that individual graphs sampled from this model do not necessarily follow the degree distribution of interest. Only averaging over many samples will give you the distribution you put in. In other words, this is equivalent to an average constraint model". Second, can you kindly present a code (and its result) which answers the first question? TIA

Comment: @user64494 That phrasing was very bad and I changed it. As for the example, I'll come back in the evening.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I'll do this tomorrow morning @user64494. Too tired ...

Comment: @user64494 I showed some examples. I also found a mistake in the documentation of `IGStaticPowerLawGame`. It should say that the fitness vector is $f_i = i^{-\alpha}$ where $\alpha = 1/(\text{exponent} - 1)$. This will be corrected in the next release. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Many thanks from me to you for your work! You are as good as your word and a real Mathematica expert. In order to accept your answer, can you add a plot of a graph with  30 vertexes (of course, without loops and multi-edges) which answers my question 1? TIA.

Comment: I have never worked with IGraph/M so I requested the plot. +1 at the moment.

Comment: Do I correctly see that the plotted graph is not connected?

Comment: Yes, it's not connected. I missed the bit that you wanted connected graphs. For that, use the Viger-Latapy method.

Comment: Accepted. How about question 2?