# Random graphs in Poincare disk

Tags: graphs-and-networks, random

The question is inspired by [that article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.03545.pdf) (
see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model) as a first reading on
the topic). This is an actual topic of modern mathematical physics. Here is my (partly successful) attempt
to implement such graphs in Mathematica.

Let  a graph be located in  `Disk[{0,0},r]` (of hyperbolic radius `R = ArcCosh[1 + 2/(1 - r^2)]`).
First, we create a random set of its vertices by

```
r = 99/100; R = ArcCosh[1 + 2/(1 - r^2)]; SeedRandom[1234]; 
vertices = Table[{RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 2*Pi}], 1][[1]], 
RandomVariate[ProbabilityDistribution[Sinh[t]/(-1 + Cosh[R]), {t, 0, R}], 1][[1]]}, {j, 1, 30}];
```

, following formula (1) from the linked article with `\[Alpha]=1`.
Second, we create a random set of its edges by

```
edges = Apply[UndirectedEdge, #] & /@ RandomSample[Subsets[vertices, {2}], 80];
```

We choose 80 random two-elemented subsets of `vertices` by `RandomSample[Subsets[vertices, {2}], 80]`
and then transform the ones to edges by `Apply[UndirectedEdge, #] & /@`.

Now

```
Graph[vertices, edges, VertexCoordinates -> 
Table[vertices[[j]] -> {vertices[[j]][[2]]*Cos[vertices[[j]][[1]]], 
vertices[[j]][[2]]*Sin[vertices[[j]][[1]]]}, {j, 1,  Dimensions[vertices][[1]]}]]
```

[image]
The coordinates of `vertices` are polar $(\phi,r)$ so we have to change these to cartesian coordinates.

The above is a somewhat unfinished work.

(i) Physicists often use the following construction: any two vertices $u$ and $v$ are connected by an edge if their hyperbolic distance
$\textrm{dist}H(u, v)$ is below a certain number $\rho$. Neither `BernoulliGraphDistribution` nor `BarabasiAlbertGraphDistribution` realize it. How to do it?

(ii) In the above edges are drawn as lines. How to draw edges as hyperbolic lines ( compare (a) and (b) in Fig. 1) ?
[image]

Answer (score 10):

**(i)** You can use [`NearestNeighborGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NearestNeighborGraph.html) with the appropriate manually defined [`DistanceFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistanceFunction.html). If that function gives you trouble, use `AdjacencyGraph@Unitize@UnitStep@DistanceMatrix[points, DistanceFunction -> ...]`.

**(ii)** Use an appropriate manually defined [`EdgeShapeFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeShapeFunction.html).

Most of the work will be constructing the correct distance function and edge shape function, but those are more of a mathematical problem than a Mathematica one.

Comment: Thank you for your comment with directions. Did you look in the linked articles? I will be waiting for a constructive answer

Comment: As I see, `EdgeShapeFunction` is not useful here at all.

Comment: In mild words,  the documentation to `DistanceFunction` (see (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistanceFunction.html)  is too poor.

Comment: If you want to use a different shape for edges than a line, you can do that with `EdgeShapeFunction`. Either you do this, or you abandon `Graph`completely and draw the graph completely manually. I am not aware of any other option. So `EdgeShapeFunction` is _the_ option to use.

Comment: Don't look at the documentation of `DistanceFunction`, but the documentation of the function that you want to use it from, i.e. `NearestNeighborGraph` or `DistanceMatrix` (whichever you choose to work with). Also, please be specific about what you tried and where you got stuck. This seems like a fairly trivial problem to solve, other than having to look up  / derive the formulas for the appropriate sampling of points on the Poincaré disk, the correct distance function, and the shape of "lines" on the disk. No, there won't be anything built-in for these. You need to do it yourself.

Comment: So don't expect to use `DistanceFunction -> "SomePredefinedValue"`. You need to define the function yourself. The same for edge shapes.

Comment: Szabolcs (@ does not work.): Sorry, I don't need directions and references. I am not a student and you are not my professor. Constructive suggestions are welcome. Do you understand me?

Comment: I gave you constructive suggestions, and outlined how to complete the task. But it seems that you are looking only for a ready-to-use solution instead of an explanation of how to do it? If you downvote answers written with a helpful intention, you can hardly expect people to help you.

Comment: Szabolcs (@ does not work.): Compare with [that question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/216364/how-to-create-random-graph-with-certain-properties).

Answer (score 10):

Szabolcs's suggestion was pretty straightforward to implement, and the math for the Poincaré disk is easy (for those who are familiar with it), so just for giggles, here's my take:

```
(* https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/115580 *)
poincareMetric[u_?VectorQ, v_?VectorQ] := 
        Abs[ArcCosh[1 + 2 SquaredEuclideanDistance[u, v]/((1 - u . u) (1 - v . v))]]

(* NURBS representation of a line on the Poincaré disk *)
poincareLine[{p1_, p2_}] := Module[{s = p1 . p2 - 1, tm = Transpose[{p2, p1}]},
        BSplineCurve[{p1, tm . ({p1 . p1, p2 . p2} - 1)/(2 s), p2}, 
                     SplineDegree -> 2, SplineKnots -> {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, 
                     SplineWeights -> {1, 1/Sqrt[1 + (Det[tm]/s)^2], 1}]]

With[{n = 200 (* number of points *),
      r = 3, (* hyperbolic radius of disk *)
      h = 0.35 (* fraction of radius to consider drawing an edge *)},
     BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42, Method -> "MersenneTwister"]; (* for reproducibility *)
                 pts = Table[With[{t = RandomReal[]}, (* hint: derive the inverse CDF *)
                                  Sqrt[(t Sinh[r/2]^2)/(1 + t Sinh[r/2]^2)]]
                                  Normalize[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 2]],
                             {n}]];
                 NearestNeighborGraph[pts, {All, h r}, 
                                      DistanceFunction -> poincareMetric, 
                                      EdgeShapeFunction -> (poincareLine[#1] &),
                                      PlotRange -> 1,
                                      Prolog -> {Directive[Opacity[1/2],
                                                           AbsoluteThickness[1]],
                                                 Circle[]}]]
```

[image: random Poincaré graph]

Comment: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etlVI.png) is a 3D version; figuring out the code for this is left as an exercise.

Comment: Thank you for your attempt to answer the question. Unfortunately, this is not it. 
If you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincaré_disk_model ,
you will know that "Hyperbolic straight lines consist of all arcs of Euclidean circles contained within the disk that are orthogonal to the boundary of the disk, plus all diameters of the disk"
and " In the Poincaré disk model, lines in the plane are defined by portions of circles having equations of the form

$$ x^{2}+y^{2}+ax+by+1=0".$$ These are not represented as splines. BTW, your comments are too poor for an average Mathematica user.

Comment: I wonder the up-voters.

Comment: Had you been open-minded and more receptive to learning things, you would have tried to find out that [circle arcs are representable as NURBS curves](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10994), and they can degenerate to straight lines if the weights are chosen appropriately. Well, I am not your professor, you are not my student, and this was just my way of having fun. I have no need to talk further if I don't feel a conversation is productive.

Comment: @user64494 user64494 always make unreasonable demand about all of the answer. So I decided to never answer his question although I have know the answer.

Comment: @user64494 Not your TA but [here](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=CkeqCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA281) is *Chapter 7: Conics and Circles* from *The NURBS Book*.