# Speeding and avoiding unwanted crash of nested Table by `NearestNeighborGraph`

Tags: matrix, graphs-and-networks, parallelization

I have a code that generates coordinate points for a 2 dimensional lattice. So the coordinates are of the form `{x,y}`. Now, I generate a graph out of these coordinates by connecting the nearest neighbors with an edge and translating it to a graph problem.
Let us say the data points are stored in object `data`. Then calculating the distances between the two coordinates, I determine if they are neighbors if the distance is `d1`, else they are not. This information is stored inside file `mat`.
This is my MWE:

```
distance[z1_,z2_]=1/2 ArcCosh[1 + (2 Abs[z1 - z2]^2)/((1 - Abs[z1]^2) (1 - Abs[z2]^2))];

(*Generating a graph from data points *)
mat = 0 IdentityMatrix[1*Length[data]];

DistributeDefinitions[d1, math, data];
(*Constructing the graph *)
mat = 
  ParallelTable[
   Table[If[0 < dist[data[[i]], data[[j]]] < 1.01 d1, 
     mat[[i, j]] = 1, mat[[i, j]] = 0], {i, 
     Length[data]}], {j, Length[data]}];

NearestNeighborGraph[data, {All, 1.01 d0}, DistanceFunction -> dist, VertexLabels -> None]
```

However, if the file size of `data` i.e., is stored in [data](https://pastebin.com/cpnSJRD2) is huge like 155k or so. The above code fails miserably, and it even crashes sometimes. Is there a way to write more efficiently and faster?
If I use `NearestNeighborGraph`, the problem is, instead of having an edge between the points, I am having two directed lines in opposite directions between the vertices. This only happens for large values of data.
The part of the graph that has the issue. It means there is only one directed arrow to some points!!! However if I write a Adjacency matrix by finding the distance between the points, and to connect them if it equals to some value, then it works! Where am I going wrong?

[image]

CORRECTIONS:
Finally, the code is working with this new change `NearestNeighborGraph[data, {All, 1.01 d0}, DistanceFunction -> dist, VertexLabels -> None]`. However, it is pathetically slow than my table code.

Comment: Mathematica has functions to work with graphs directly https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NearestNeighborGraph.html -- creating a table with 24 billion elements is not the way to go

Comment: You are probably looking for something like `NearestNeighborGraph`.

Comment: Besides the point BarryCarter pointed out, here are some notes on your code:  you're building the matrix with `ParallelTable`, there is no need to set `mat[[ ... ]]` inside, If you want to do that, remove `mat =` and use `ParallelDo`. For creating a zero matrix, you can use `ConstantArray`.

Comment: @BarryCarter I completely agree with you. But the distance can have a metric inside. So, the distance have to be calculated in a non-trivial way. For instance, in hyperbolic case, we can have Poincare metric

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher There is a subtlety which I forgot to mention. Please feel fre to have a look in my previous comment. The distance between the points is not Euclidean. For e.g., it `distance[z1_,z2_]=1/2 ArcCosh[1 + (2 Abs[z1 - z2]^2)/((1 - Abs[z1]^2) (1 - Abs[z2]^2))];`, where `z` stores coordinates point in 2D.

Comment: @BenIzd, Thanks, I again emphasize the subtlety.

Comment: You could use `DistanceFunction` to set any distance function you want, but a complicated enough distance function may end up looking at all pairs of distances.

Comment: @BarryCarter Does the `DistanceFunction` will still work even if the data point set is one dimensional i.e., without any partitioning?

Comment: I haven't checked, but, in theory, it should work for any DistanceFunction. Oh wait, it might assume things like the triangle inequality or something

Comment: @BarryCarter I can share a small data set in my question also. I would be very interested in implementing the approach mentioned by and others!

Comment: Please do share data, I'm sort of curious myself now

Comment: @BarryCarter I have aded the data file link in the main text. Any more inputs from your side is infinitely valuable. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138327/discussion-between-barry-carter-and-shamina).

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/269272) already?

Comment: @J.M. This is a wonderful link! Many thanks! :) 
I am gonna have a look. At least, I will see where I failed in the distance function.

Comment: @J.M.'spersistentexhaustion I tried your very nicely written code. But I think I am having some problems, maybe because of my ignorance.

Comment: @J.M.'spersistentexhaustion The problem is, instead of having an edge between the points, I am having two directed lines in opposite directions between the vertices. This only happens for large values of data. I edited my question accordingly to implement your code in it.

Comment: If you pass `NearestNeighborGraph` the option `DirectedEdges -> False`, does it work? I'd imagine it's happening due to numerical errors causing the `distance` function to be asymmetrical, though, and if so those errors might warrant correction somehow instead of just being "papered over" by setting `DirectedEdges -> False`. I'm not sure, though.

Comment: @thorimur thanks for this suggestion. I tried this already, however, this doesn't;t solve the problem completely. But, you will see the change in the main question now where it seems to work now. Only problem is, it is pathetically slow. You are right it is connected with the distance function that is not always numerically equal but some errors.