# What is the difference between a "GraphDistribution" and Distribution and can I convert between them?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

What is the difference between a GraphDistribution and a Distribution?  I would like to make a GraphDistribution out of the ZipfDistribution and build RandomGraphs[]'s from that.  i.e. is it possible to roll your own GraphDistributions?

```
data = EdgeCount /@ 
   RandomGraph[BernoulliGraphDistribution[6, 0.4], 10^3];
Show[Histogram[data, Automatic, "PDF"],
 DiscretePlot[PDF[BinomialDistribution[15, 0.4], m], {m, 0, 15}, 
  Joined -> True]]
```

[image]

Comment: See [that related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/216364/how-to-create-random-graph-with-certain-properties.).

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for, i.e. creating my own XGraphDistribution where X is a Mathematica distribution.